# Credit Card Equation (in C#)

Tags: c#, math

I have a homework question that I need some **verification** on. I got the correct answer for the first part of the question. However, the second part of the question isn't working out so well. I'm not sure if my calculations are off or if the test data is wrong. *(it's happened a few times already this year)*.

We are suppose to design a console application that will solve how many months it'll take to pay off a loan.

**I can't use any code I haven't learned yet; just basic code. (no loops, arrays, etc)**

The formula is: 
N = -(1/30) * ln(1+b/p(1-(1+i)^30)) / ln(1+i)

**n** = months

**ln** = log function

**b** = credit card balance

**p** = monthly payment

**i** = daily interest rate (annual interest rate/365)

> **Test Data for Question 1:**
>
> Credit Card Balance: $5000
>
> Monthly Payment: $200
>
> Annual Rate: 0.28
>
> **My answer: 38 months**
>
> **Test Data for Question 2:**
>
> Credit Card Balance: $7500
>
> Monthly Payment: $125
>
> Annual Rate: 0.22
>
> **Unable to get an answer**

**My solution:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal creditcardbalance, monthlypayment;
    double calculation, months, annualpercentrate;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the credit card balance in dollars and cents: ");
    creditcardbalance = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the monthly payment amount in dollars and cents: ");
    monthlypayment = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the annual rate percentage as a decimal: ");
    annualpercentrate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    calculation = (Math.Log((1 + (double)(creditcardbalance / monthlypayment) * (1 - (Math.Pow(1 + (annualpercentrate / 365), 30)))))) / (Math.Log((1 + (annualpercentrate / 365))));
    months = (-0.033333333333333333) * calculation;


    Console.WriteLine("\nIt will take {0:F0} months to pay off the loan.", months);
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to take the logarithm of a negativ number. Thats why you get  "NaN" (not a number) as a result.

But why is 1+b/p(1-(1+i)^30) negative in the second example?
Well, that is simple. Because your monthly interest is greater than your monthly payment!

$7500 * 0.22 / 12  = 137.5$

Since your monthly payment is just $125, you will take an infinite amount of months (speak: never) to pay of your debt.

NaN is the programming languages way to represent a non-computable result.

So, you don't have a programming problem, you have a debt problem. Maybe this is a question for [money.stackexchange.com](http://money.stackexchange.com)  ;-)

Comment: NaN is a distinct concept from Inf. Log of a negative is complex not infinite. So it will take an imaginary number of months, not infinite

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I editet my awnser to "does not compute". ;-)
My last Math-lecutre is long time ago, i just assumed it would be somthing like infinity, but now that I thought about it, it doesn't realy makes much sense.

Comment: So, in short, sounds like a case of "bad sample data" which OP noted has happened already?

Comment: I don't think it's so much "bad sample data" as it is an exercise in "how to return a friendly error message and gracefully exit a program when you hit an error". In this case, when interest > payment, rather than "NaN', something like "Current payment is insufficient to repay debt"...

Comment: Or it serves the purpose to "get the students thinking". It took me a while to realise that the code wasn't bad, but the input data.